# Finding absolute value with if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, absolute-value

I have 2 int variables which the user needs to enter, and I need to find the absolute value of their difference, is there a way to do it on the same principle I have started in this code?

```
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    int yourfloor, elefloor, desfloor;`enter code here`
    System.out.println("Please enter your current floor");
    yourfloor = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the elevator current floor(before inviting)");
    elefloor = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter your destination floor");
    desfloor = scn.nextInt();

    int getTime = yourfloor - elefloor;
    if (getTime<0);
    {getTime*(-1)};
```

Comment: Seems your code has an unwanted semicolon here , `if (getTime<0); ` , other than that, what issues you face with your code?

Comment: the problem wa with {getTime*(-1)};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the ternary operator?

```
//ASSIGNMENT   CONDITION             ? WHAT IF TRUE           : WHAT IF FALSE
int getTime = (yourfloor > elefloor) ? (yourfloor - elefloor) : (elefloor-yourfloor);
```

Or by changing your code to work:

```
int getTime = yourfloor - elefloor;
if (getTime<0) {
   getTime *= -1;
}
```

The `;` at the end of your `if` completed the if statement - so the `*(-1)` was *always* executed. In addition, you need to use `*=` instead of `*`, because if you just multiply it, it will not do anything with the result, whereas `*=` is short for: `getTime = getTime * -1`, which will assign it back to `getTime`.

Or of cause you could use `Math.abs()`...

Comment: Seems like a very convoluted way to get the absolute value, the ternary statement isn't too readable (parenthesis would help), but to a newbie would probably shy them away from using it. Not a natural need for the ternary operator. I think `Math.abs()` should be preferred, since he is asking specifically about absolute value.

Comment: Right. But this has the feel of an "assignment" like question - so probably Math isn't allowed. See my edit of "making it right".

Comment: And... check out the implementation of Math.abs: `return (a < 0) ? -a : a;` ternary operator all over again...

Answer (score -1):

Try [`abs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(double)) which takes a number of any type as a parameter and returns the absolute value of it, in the same type.

```
abs(-3.1) == 3.1
```

So you could write:

```
int getTime = abs(yourfloor - elefloor);
```